# Copy files between two SSH clients diretctly

Tags: ssh, scp

Our two SSH client *only* machines have access to another remote server with the *same* user account, and we want to copy files between the two clients over the wire. Can we configure this type of small local *hub-spoke* network to make the direct file transfer between the clients pass through the server transparently, and how?

For example, we have the hub-spoke network configuration below, where the hub is the SSH server, the spokes are SSH clients and the clients need copy files directly.

```
Node    IP              Client  Server  Port    User    Status

A       192.168.1.1     Y       N       N/A     alice   authenticated
B       192.168.1.2     Y       N       N/A     bob     authenticated
C       192.168.1.3     Y       Y       22      shared  authorized

$ alice@A: ssh-keygen
$ alice@A: ssh-copy-id shared@C
$ bob@B:   ssh-keygen
$ bob@B:   ssh-copy-id shared@C
```

Now, we can copy a file from *alice@A* to *bob@B* yet neither directly nor efficiently below.

```
$ alice@A: scp myfile shared@C:~
$ bob@B:   scp shared@C:~/myfile .
```

However, we want to customize the network configuration not to firstly drop the file to *shared@C* but copy it from *alice@A* to *bob@B* directly.

*@chepner* proposed *scp -3*. I think that we have to change the hub-spoke network configuration fundamentally, i.e. the hub must act as SSH client, the spokes must run as SSH servers, then the servers can copy files directly through the transparent client proxy. Here's the [example](https://serverfault.com/questions/560970/copy-data-through-ssh-tunnel-over-multiple-hops).

Comment: Are you looking for the `-3` option? "-3      Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the local
             host." (The command would have to be run on the shared-access server, of course.)

Comment: How can the server *scp* to the clients? Neither TCP connections nor tunnels have been established in advance.

Comment: you can probably use proxyjump in the config

Answer (score 0):

provided you can go from C to B, then the following should work:

in the ssh config file on `A`, define both `B` and `C`:

```
Host C
  Hostname c-whatever.contoso.local
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  User charlie
  ForwardAgent yes

Host B
  Hostname b-whatever.contoso.local
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  User bob
  ProxyJump C
```

ssh to `B` will proxy all traffic via `C`

Comment: Our configuration has only the *one* SSH hub server. Either *ProxyCommand* or *PrxoyJump* must take advantage of the *chain* of SSH proxy servers in essence. Is that right?

Comment: To be precise, the *scp* must origin from SSH client and the destination must run as SSH server regardless through SSH proxies or not.

Comment: yes, you need to be able to ssh to the target. If you can't connect to the target then there's no way to initiate traffic to it. Best bet if it was the other way (A and C can only connect to B, not the other way) is to run rsync from A to C and from B to C